# Casting a container of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, casting, containers, shared-ptr

I have a method

```
void foo(list<shared_ptr<Base>>& myList);
```

Which I'm trying to call with a two different types of lists, one of DerivedClass1 and one of DerivedClass2

```
list<shared_ptr<DerivedClass1>> myList1; 
foo(myList1);
list<shared_ptr<DerivedClass2>> myList2; 
foo(myList2);
```

However this obviously generates a compiler error

```
error: a reference of type "std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Base>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Base>>> &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "std::list<boost::shared_ptr<DerivedClass1>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<DerivedClass1>>>"
```

Is there any easy way to cast a container of shared_ptr? Of alternate containers that can accomplish this?

**Update**: Thanks to everyone who responded. Working within the confines of the language, it seems the best way to go while keeping the method 'as-is' is to use a container of shared_ptr and pass exactly that in (creating a new list at the call site).

I guess I pretty much already knew this, but I remembered reading about other parts of the boost library dealing with containers of shared_ptr and thought maybe it was solved more elegantly by someone else already. From my own further research however these seem to be geared more towards reducing overhead of shared_ptr in cases where a number of pointers are owned exclusively (therefore requiring a single lock per container rather than one per object in the container).

Thanks again, you guys are all awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cast a container of one type to a container of another type.  There are a few ways to create a new container from an existing container, if the type of object stored by the existing container is convertible to the type of object stored by the new container:

You can use `std::copy` to do the conversion element-by-element:

```
list<shared_ptr<Base> > baseList;
list<shared_ptr<Derived> > derivedList;
std::copy(derivedList.begin(), derivedList.end(), std::back_inserter(baseList));
```

You can also directly construct `baseList` using the begin and end iterators from `derivedList`:

```
list<shared_ptr<Base> > baseList(derivedList.begin(), derivedList.end());
```

If your function can take a const reference instead, you can construct a temporary in the function call:

```
typedef list<shared_ptr<Base> > BaseList;
foo(BaseList(derivedList.begin(), derivedList.end()));
```

Comment: Why would you use `copy` when `list` has a range-based constructor?

Comment: As demonstrated in the second example?

Answer (score 7):

Change `foo` so that it follows STL conventions and takes iterators:

```
template< typename It >
void foo(It begin, It end);
```

Then pass iterators into your lists

```
list<shared_ptr<DerivedClass1>> myList1;
foo(myList1.begin(), myList1.end());
list<shared_ptr<DerivedClass2>> myList2;
foo(myList2.begin(), myList2.end());
```

And everything should work just fine.

***Edit***:
Note that this isn't anything special to smart pointers. A `std::list<T1*>&` cannot be initialized with a `std::list<T2*>`, even if `T2` derives from `T1`.

Comment: but isn't it weird that you should have to use a template function for what is well handled by basic inheritance in other cases?

Comment: @Jamie Cook: Nope. That is never handled by basic inheritance in any case. A container of Derived is not a container of Base. If that was allowed then you would be able to add elements of type Base to that container inside the function, breaking the type system.

Comment: @Jamie: `T<A>` and `T<B>` are completely different classes for any template `T` and any different `A` and `B`, no matter how A and B are related.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Not true in general, ironically shared_ptr itself is one such example. Generally speaking some template classes choose to allow such conversions via special templated copy constructors.

Comment: And plus, if I was going to make it templated... why wouldn't I just modify the signature to be template<class T> foo(list<shared_ptr<T>>& l)? I know the begin/end iterator stuff is used widely in the STL but what practical benefits can it give here?

Comment: @Terry: The copy constructor allows one kind of `shared_ptr` to be converted to another, but they remain different types. It is possible (but confusing) to construct an inheritance hierarchy within the specializations of a single template, technically. Anyway, containers rely on range insertion for conversion-initialization, as in this answer.

Comment: @Jamie: Iterators are the minimal interface for… well, iteration. A container allows you to use one argument rather than two, but you still have to call `begin()` and `end()` on it inside anyway. A function in terms of iterators works with any container, as well as ranges within a container, C-style arrays, I/O streams, generator functions, etc.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - point taken. I've taken to using BOOST_FOREACH so my calling of begin/end is somewhat hidden from me most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `list<shared_ptr<Base>>` and `list<shared_ptr<DerivedClass1>>` (or even  `shared_ptr<Base>` and `shared_ptr<DerivedClass1>`) are completely different types, even if `DerivedClass1` inherits from `Base`. So casting one to the other would in fact be wrong.

Consider the case when `foo` attempts to add new elements of type `Base` to `myList`. If you could cast `myList1` into a `list<shared_ptr<Base>>` (e.g. with an old-style C cast), and passed it to `foo`, the result would not be nice.

So the only proper solution I see is to create a new `list<shared_ptr<Base>>` object and copy the contents of the other list into it, then pass that to `foo`, as is demonstrated by @James McNellis.

Comment: but still... if the method foo took a single element then you would be able to call foo(static_pointer_cast<Base>(objectOfTypeDerivedClass1))

Comment: @Jamie Cook, yes but that's a different question (I clarified my post a bit). Btw is static_pointer_cast a nonstandard VC++ extension?

Comment: @Jamie: Yes, there are special rules between `shared_ptr<Base>` and `shared_ptr<Derived>` because `shared_ptr` emulates a pointer. However, different containers are totally distinct. If you want the same function to work for containers of different types, use templates (compile-time polymorphism), or store pointers to base and use runtime polymorphism.

Comment: The `shared_ptr<>` is confusing the issue.  You also cannot cast `list<Base*>` to `list<Derived*>`.  They are unrelated types, as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: yeah I guess it is a different question... perhaps I should have clarified that the argument list would be const. But I don't think that changes anything meaningful, the compiler still won't be able to do any easy conversion. boost::static_pointer_cast is from boost::shared_ptr and basically does what it says (there is also boost::dynamic_pointer_cast)

Answer (score 0):

The classical explanation why that wouldn't be a good idea goes as follows:

If you have a `list<Apple*>` nicely filled with Apples, and you were able to pass it to a function accepting a `list<Fruit*>`, then there is no stopping the function from putting new Oranges in the list. A `list<Fruit*>` is simply not substitutable for a `list<Apple*>` and there exists no relationship.

If you want a function that could work both with a `list<Apple*>` and `list<Orange*>`, you could use templates (whether with Iterators, or taking the Container itself, or taking a `list<T*>` - entirely your choice.

---

If you really badly wanted to pass a `list<Apple*>` as if a `list<Fruit*>`, then I suppose it would be technically possible to come up with proxies for the container / iterators, that use type erasure and what-not to cast the pointers internally / stop invalid casts (putting Oranges into list of Apples), so that you could make the function instead take a `list_proxy<Fruit*>` which accepts lists of derived types.

Something along the lines of (just a beginning):

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

template <class T>
class ListWrapperBaseAux
{
public:
    virtual ~ListWrapperBaseAux() {}
    virtual T* front() = 0;
};

template <class T, class U>
class ListWrapperAux: public ListWrapperBaseAux<T>
{
    std::list<U*>* list_ref;
public:
    ListWrapperAux(std::list<U*>* list_ref): list_ref(list_ref) {}
    virtual T* front() { return dynamic_cast<T*>(list_ref->front()); }
};

template <class T>
class ListProxy
{
    boost::shared_ptr<ListWrapperBaseAux<T> > list_ref;
public:
    template <class U>
    ListProxy(std::list<U*>& li): list_ref(new ListWrapperAux<T, U>(&li)) {}
    T* front() { return list_ref->front(); }
};

struct Fruit
{
    virtual ~Fruit() {}
};

struct Apple: Fruit {};
struct Orange: Fruit {};

void bake(ListProxy<Fruit> li)
{
    Fruit* f = li.front();
}

int main()
{
    std::list<Apple*> apples;
    bake(apples);

    std::list<Orange*> oranges;
    bake(oranges);
}
```